# AWK - print last column along with empty value

Tags: linux, shell-script, awk

We can print the last column of each line in a file using `$NF` if we don't know the last column number.

But I facing difficulty is the last column has an empty value.

**For example,** Parsing `who` command

```
$ who
root     tty1         2018-01-25 09:36
root     pts/0        2018-05-30 07:39 (192.168.1.134)
root     pts/1        2018-05-28 23:12 (192.168.1.134)
root     pts/2        2018-06-01 10:01 (192.168.1.188)
```

Getting result:

```
$ who | awk '{print $NF}'
09:36
(192.168.1.134)
(192.168.1.134)
(192.168.1.188)
```

Expected Result

```
(192.168.1.134)
(192.168.1.134)
(192.168.1.188)
```

Let me know the possibilities of getting expected result in a one-liner.

**EDIT 1:** The above scenario is only an example. I don't like to change the delimiter to achieve the result.

**EDIT 2:** nothing (an empty line of output) from the lines that have fewer fields than the maximum

Comment: @Archemar `who` shows only the hostname/IP for non-local logins.

Comment: Considering the general case: how do you define which field you want? Do you want the last field from the lines that have the most fields, and nothing from the lines that have less fields than the maximum? Or do you have some a priori information about the data?

Comment: @ikkachu Thanks for the suggestions. I have updated my question.

Comment: Do you want an empty line of output for input lines that have fewer than 5 fields or skip those lines altogether?

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas, `AWK - print last column along with empty value`. Your answer worked for me with a small change which I did in the comment.

Comment: I'll share the fun I found in `who --help` : `If ARG1 ARG2 given, -m presumed: 'am i' or 'mom likes' are usual.` ; the two args have no other purposes than to make it possible to request in a cheeky way your user's infos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To only output the last column of rows that have the max number of columns, you could do something like:

```
who | awk '
  NF > max  {max = NF; output = ""}
  NF == max {output = output $NF ORS}
  END       {printf "%s", output}'
```

To output one row for every row of input, but empty for rows that don't have the max number of columns:

```
who | awk '
  NF > max {max = NF}
  {n[NR] = NF}
  NF == max {last[NR] = $NF}
  END {for (i = 1; i <= NR; i++) print n[i] == max ? last[i] : ""}'
```

Comment: Works like charm!!! `{max = NF; output = "\n"}` gave me the result i expects. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the last field only from the lines that have the most fields, you'll need to read through the data twice: once to find out the highest number of fields, and another time to print the fields. Reading just once doesn't cut it: any line could have more fields than the ones before, and there's no way to know.

With `awk` (note the filename is given twice):

```
awk -vfields=0 'FNR==NR {if (NF > fields) fields=NF; next} 
     NF >= fields { print $NF } NF < fields {print ""}' file file
```

If `file` contains

```
foo bar
one two three four
1 2 3
a b c d
```

this prints the fourth field, or empty for lines that don't have it:

```
four

d
```

That, of course doesn't work with a pipe, you'll have to use a temporary file.

An alternative solution could cache the to-be-printed fields until a line with more fields appears, as in [Stéphane's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/447261/170373).

Answer (score 1):

Check if the 5th field matches `\(.*\)`, and print it if it does.

```
who | awk '$5 ~ /\(.*\)/{print $5}'
```

If you are only interested in `ip` addresses then change the regex:

```
who |  awk '$5 ~ /\((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\)/{print $5}'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to get the last column if this column is available, use the fact that lines that you *don't* want have only four columns:

```
who | awk 'NF > 4 { print $NF }'
```

or, to get similar data,

```
w -hi | awk '{ print $3 }'
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, But as I mentioned in the question, How can we achieve without knowing the field number `4`.

Comment: @SivaPrasath You do know that `who` outputs five fields, or four if the user is logged in locally, because you have read the manual for `who`.

Comment: as mentioned in the question, `who` is just an example. I would like to achieve the result without knowing the max field as answered by @Stéphane

Comment: @SivaPrasath I'd still argue that you know what you're parsing, or you would have no clue what data you wanted. If it's the output of a command, you will obviously read its manual to know what kind of output it produces. If it's a data file, then it most likely also follows some sort of pattern.